# jshint and reserved words

Tags: angularjs, jshint, reserved-words

During applying jshint with angular boilerplate it give an error message:

> [L249:C26] W024: Expected an identifier and instead saw 'delete' (a 
>   reserved word).
>         return $http.delete('/cv/' + cv.id)
>
> Warning: Task "jshint:src" failed. Use --force to continue.

How could it be configured/skipped ?

Thanks.

Comment: Jshit is a great typo :-)

Comment: Ha ha... Great title. :D

Comment: sorry  :( 
I couldn't find the edit link :) quickly

Comment: This looks like a bug, but I can't reproduce it in the current version of JSHint.

Comment: Thanks, upgrade to 2.8.0 resolved the issue.